# Java: sum and median for an array of numbers

Tags: java, arrays, sum, mean

How would you write the constructor and methods for the mean and sum 
for:
 an array of numbers and those numbers are 
double data[] = {3.0, 15.0, 7.0, 27.0}?

thanks

Comment: What are your efforts so far?

Comment: public class Stats {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double data[]={3.0, 15.0, 7.0, 27.0};
          }
    double sum = 0;
for( int i : data); {
    sum += i;
System.out.println(sum);
}}

Comment: Please post the code in your question. Just edit it.

Comment: I would suggest that you post this code in the question itself after proper indentation

Comment: You won't need a class with a constructor for such a trivial task, just stick to static methods.

Comment: I'm sorry if it's not properly indented. It's my first time using this website and I had no idea to put it in, so I just copied and pasted from my program.

Answer (score 1):

Take a step back from the assignment and look at what it's really asking you.

First of all: the sum of an array is all the items in that array added together. 
Solution: loop through each array item and add it to a `total` variable;

Second: the median of an array is the sum of each array item divided by the array's length. 
Solution: use your calculate sum method to get the sum, and divide it by the array's length. 
Example:

```
public class Stats {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double data[] = {3.0, 15.0, 7.0, 27.0};
        System.out.printf("Sum: %d", getSum(data));
        System.out.printf("Median: %d", getMedian(data));
    }

    public static double getMedian(double[] input) {
        return getSum(input) / input.length;
    }

    public static double getSum(double[] input) {
        double total = 0;
        for (double d : input) {
            total += d;
        }
        return total;
    }
}
```

If you want to take a more object-oriented approach, you can store the double array in a separate class with helper methods to perform calculations, like so:

```
public class Stats {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double data[] = {3.0, 15.0, 7.0, 27.0};
        DoubleArrayUtilities utilities = new DoubleArrayUtilities(data));
        System.out.printf("Sum: %d", utilities.getSum());
        System.out.printf("Median: %d", utilities.getMedian());
    }

}

public class DoubleArrayUtilities {

    private double[] data;

    public DoubleArrayUtilities(double[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public double getMedian() {
        return getSum() / data.length;
    }

    public double getSum() {
        double total = 0;
        for (double d : data) {
            total += d;
        }
        return total;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any question where the person asking question hasn't put any efforts to solve it; shouldn't be answered.

Comment: Some people really just don't know where to even start with an assignment. We've all been there, and if helping them requires me to post a compilable example, I'll be glad to help.

Comment: I know where you are trying to come from. But off late, too many students share their assignment problems on SO without giving any thoughts about how to solve it. In long run, i.e. if they wish to code later on, then this might hurt them. We need to at least get them thinking and for such questions we can guide them about what to think of using comments section instead of sharing the actual answer cause that will make them more lazy.

Comment: I'm sorry if I came off as lazy, I just didn't know where to start so I was asking for anyone's help on the general idea.

Comment: Also Thank you so much for answering! It's really helpful.